# How to remove the single quote in Vlookup formula VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Hi i  have writing a code for pull the data from one workbook to another by using of Vlookup and have struggling with below code. the code is give the `#NAME?` error and formula of the cell is`= VLOOKUP( 'A2',[mis.xlsx]Borrowerwise!$A$1:$Z$1260,16,FALSE)`. The issue is lookup value `A2` having singe quotation so how can i remove the single quotation ? Note -if remove the single quote manually the formula is working.

```
Sub Vlook()
 Dim LR As Long
 Dim Rg2, L As Range
    Rg2 = Workbooks("mis").Sheets(1).Range("A2:Z10000")
 ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Activate
            With ActiveSheet
                ActiveSheet.Range("a1").Select
                LR = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1
                .Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "0"
                .Range("a1").Select
                Range("a1").End(xlToRight).Select
                Set L = ActiveSheet.Range("A2")
                With ActiveCell
                .Offset(1, 1).Resize(LR).FormulaR1C1 = "= vlookup( " & L.Address(False, False) & "," & Rg2.Address(True, True, xlR1C1, xlExternal) & ",16,False)"
              End With
              End With

 End Sub
```

Comment: A good explanation about it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790662/when-writing-string-to-a-cell-vba-inserts-extra-single-quotation-marks

Comment: Hope this topic will help you
[Remove single quote VBA function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20662375/7876875)